# Sockets: my select() function logic has undefined behavior

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I implemented a program that receives from one socket and sends/receives from the other socket.

For this i use polling of select(), in socket 1, i receive data at a high data rate, while in the other socket i receive periodic message and requests to receive data from the first socket.

When there is no request "from socket 2" to delegate the data from socket 1 to socket2 , i receive data from socket 1 normal and with no problem. However, say i received two requests "socket 2" while data is being received in socket 1, the second request breaks the the data reception as if it could no longer keep up with rate "rate isn't high really is only 150 Hz".

The pseudo code i do in the main():

```
fd_set readfds, rd_fds, writefds, wr_fds;
struct timeval tv;

do
  {
    do
      {
        rd_fds = readfds;
        wr_fds = writefds;
        FD_ZERO (&rd_fds);
        FD_SET (sock1, &rd_fds);
        FD_SET (sock2, &rd_fds);
        FD_SET (sock1, &wr_fds);
        tv.tv_sec = 0;
        tv.tv_usec = 20;
        int ls = sock2 + 1;
        rslt = select (ls, &rd_fds, &wr_fds, NULL, &tv);
      }
    while (rslt == -1 && errno == EINTR);


    if (FD_ISSET (sock1, &rd_fds))
      {
        rs1 = recvfrom (sock1, buff, size of the buff, ....);
        if (rs1 > 0)
          {
             if (rs1 = alive message)
                {
                /* system is alive; */
                }
             else if (rs1 == request message)
               {
                /* store Request info (list or vector) */
               }
             else {}
          }
     }

    if (FD_ISSET (StructArg.sock2, &rd_fds))
      {
        rs2 = recv (sock2, ..., 0);
        if (rs2 > 0)
          {
            if ( /* Message (high rate) is from sock 2 */ )
              {
                /* process this message and do some computation */

                int sp1 = sendto (sock1, .....);

                if (sp1 < 0)
                  {
                    perror ("Failed data transmission ");
                  }
                else
                  {
                    /* increase some counters */
                  }
              }
          }
      }

    if (FD_ISSET (sock1, &wr_fds))
      {
        /*
           if there info stored in the list
           do some calculaitons then send to sock 1
         */
        if (sendto (sock1, ... ...) < 0)
          {
            perror ("Failed data transmission");
          }
        else
          {
            /* increase counter */
          }

      }

    FD_CLR (sock1, &rd_fds);
    FD_CLR (sock2, &rd_fds);
  }
while (1);
```

Again, the question is, why does receiving from sock1 is interrupted if a request is received from sock2, while i am receiving from sock1 (fast messages), i expect interleaved messages in the output based on the timestamps in the message.

Comment: I attempted to fix your indentation, but your program had more close braces in than open braces, meaning it was hard to see what you were trying to do. I took a guess.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to understand what you are talking about here, but have you configured the sockets to be non-blocking?

Comment: The sockets are both non-blocking sir.

Comment: ls should be set to (max(sock1,sock2)+1)

Comment: Also, what is the benefit of the 20-microsecond timeout?  AFAICT all it does is add extra CPU overhead without adding any functionality.  Unless there is some non-socket-related action that needs to happen every 20 microseconds, I suggest leaving the timeout argument set to NULL.

Comment: @jeremy , i thought that set to max(sock1, sock2) + 1 should resolve the issue, but it didn't. Is setting the fd set within the loop so the way it is done? I also removed the 20 sec and put NULL in the select, it bears no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Note that nearly all socket functions can block execution unless you've created the socket with the O_NONBLOCK option:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sendto.html

And you'll also have to handle the case where recvfrom only gives you a partial read - unless you use MSG_WAITALL:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html

Personally, I'd use a multi-threaded implementation which can have threads just sit and wait for data on each socket.

As to your final question:

> why does receiving from sock1 is interrupted if a request is received from sock2, while i am receiving from sock1 (fast messages), i expect interleaved messages in the output based on the timestamps in the message.

You are slave to the network stack's implementation and there are nearly no guarantees about the sending or receiving of data on one socket relative to another.  You are only guaranteed that the data *within* a socket is properly ordered.

Comment: both sockets are nonblocking. Let me just elaborate directly. The problem i am encountering, is that when i am receiving data at the first socket "the sockets are non blocking but looping , but select blocks only for 20usec" , a request from socket 2, stops the reception of data at sockets 1, which does not make sense, because if there is data in fd_set , then it should go and give me my message and 20use is way sufficient. something ain't right in my logic, the computer just gives you what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect interleaved messages in the output based on the timestamps in the message.

Your expectation is without foundation. If there is data in either socket receive buffer, `select()` will fire. That's all you can rely on. You don't have any guarantee about timestamps being observed and ordered as between multiple sockets.

Comment: i believe you misunderstood, actually all the messages have designed headers , those headers have timestamps and counters. so when i said i expect, i mean the timestamp generated by the sender once it was transmitted, so the message must have timestamps. Let me just rephrase the question then, is what i am doing with the select () is common practice. it waits for whatever is available as data. correct ? if so why does it stop receiving from FD_ISSET of socket2. The observation is , it receives .....if request is done before, if i do another request while data is being received, it stops